# Create MDL Switch Programmatically with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, material-design, material-design-lite

I have a quick question that I can't figure out regarding MDL.

This is working perfectly using just HTML:

```
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
    <input onchange="handleDisableEnabled(this)" type="checkbox" id="switch-1"
           class="mdl-switch__input" checked>
    </label>
<span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
```

But when I do something like this:

```
<span id='foo'></span>

<script>
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = '<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
<input onchange="handleDisableEnabled(this)" type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input" checked></label>
<span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>';
</script>
```

It simply outputs a normal checkbox with no formatting. Is there any way to create a switch via Javascript? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `componentHandler.upgradeElement(elementName)` to instantiate a dynamically created MDL component. See [How the Component Handler works](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/How-the-Component-Handler-works) for more details. For example:

```js
let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
let label = document.createElement('label');
let input = document.createElement('input');
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = 'Switch';

Object.assign(label, {className: 'mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect'});
label.setAttribute('for', 'switch-1');
Object.assign(input, {type: 'checkbox', className: 'mdl-switch__input', id: 'switch-1'});
Object.assign(span, {className: 'mdl-switch__label'});

fragment.appendChild(label);
label.appendChild(input);
label.appendChild(span);

componentHandler.upgradeElement(label);
document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Material Design Lite Switch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>

</html>
```